# What's the purpose of IUnknown member functions in END_COM_MAP?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, atl

ATL END_COM_MAP macro is defined as follows:

```
#define END_COM_MAP() \
    __if_exists(_GetAttrEntries) {{NULL, (DWORD_PTR)_GetAttrEntries, _ChainAttr }, }\
    {NULL, 0, 0}}; return _entries;} \
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef( void) throw() = 0; \
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release( void) throw() = 0; \
    STDMETHOD(QueryInterface)(REFIID, void**) throw() = 0;
```

It is intended to be used within definition of classes inherited from COM interfaces, for example:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CMyClass :
    public CComCoClass<CMyClass, &MyClassGuid>,
    public CComObjectRoot,
    public IMyComInterface
{
public:
    BEGIN_COM_MAP( CMyClass )
        COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY( IMyComInterface)
    END_COM_MAP()
};
```

This means that QueryInterface(), AddRef() and Release() are declared as pure virtual in this class. Since I don't define their implementation this class should be uncreatable. Yet ATL successfully instantiates it.

How does it work and why are those IUnknown member functions redeclared here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a while since I used ATL but, IIRC, what ends up being instantiated is not `CMyClass`, but `CComObject<CMyClass>`.

`CComObject` implements `IUnknown` and inherits from its template parameter.

Edit: The "[Fundamentals of ATL COM Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c43h4867.aspx)" page on MSDN nicely illustrates what's going on.

Comment: And there's a slew of other CComObjects, as mentioned in the referenced article. Each variation customizes IUnknown behavior, either QueryInterface or lifetime management (AddRef/Release).